# How to change the date format when the file is spooled in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently i'm generating a export where the date format is actually dd/mm/yyyy but when i spool it and see it is coming as dd/mmm/yyyy in a readable format

For example if the date in my real file is 06/10/2014 in the spool it automatically is coming 06-Oct-2014. But i don't want this format. How to retain the original one?

Comment: Change `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_2013.htm#SQLRF53073

Comment: The date in your *real* file? What file is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your date column to char representation before exporting

```
to_char(date_column, 'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as an *original date format*. Oracle stores dates without any format. When you're spooling your data, you either have to specifically indicate a format *or* Oracle uses a system default format.

So, if you consistantly want the format to be `dd/mm/yyyy` then you could change the *default format* for just a session with

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy'
```